# Converting a Swift string which contains multiple file paths to an AppleScript list

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, finder

Suppose there are two file paths:

/Users/xxx/Desktop/AWP2014.epub

/Users/xxx/Desktop/algorithms.epub

And then using the following code to form a string:

```
var pathList = ""
for (index,path) in lastFilePaths.enumerated()
{
    guard let path = path else {continue}
    pathList += path
    if index != lastFilePaths.endIndex-1
    {
        pathList += ","
    }
}
```

Now how can I convert this string to applescript's files list? So I can use this list like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
set myFilesList to listConvertFromSwiftString
move myFilesList to myDestinFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding in Swift, why on Earth would you want to use Finder, via AppleScript, to move files instead of `FileManager.moveItem(atPath:toPath:)`?

Comment: My case is special, I just want this function to be excuted by Finder, not by my App. @foo

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
    let scriptString = 
        "tell application \"Finder\"\n" +
        "set theList to \(String(describing: pathList)) as list\n" +
        "set myNewList to {}\n" +
        "repeat with pathItem in theList\n" +
        "set newPath to pathItem\n" +
        "set end of myNewList to (newPath as POSIX file)\n" +
        "end repeat\n" +
        "end tell\n"
```